# Cron Job configration in ehost

Tags: cron

First of all I am not a developer.
I am using Magento 2.1 community edition and it is hosted in ehost.com.
I installed it using FTP. The setup has done successfully and front end and back end are working good. 
Once I try to install a new theme/extensions, I am getting an error on readiness check saying: Cron job is not configured. 
I contact ehost customer support, they are saying cronjob has to be created from my side. I go through the help on Magento. I realised that there is no cron on var folder, but I found it in folder /update. 
Is there anybody who can help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have ssh login details? You have to set up a cron via the server itself rather than within Magento.

Comment: Do not publish any ssh details here by the way.

Comment: Do you use Magento 1 or 2? Do you have access to a UI/panel/admin of your hosting provider?

Comment: I am using Magento 2.1 and I have access to all features in cpanel

Comment: @Andy  I do have the ssh details how can I pass it to you?

Comment: I'm not after the details. I'm just getting further information. You should be careful with those details also. If you've no experience with setting up cron jobs then you might be best asking ehost if they can provide you with a system administrator. They may charge you for it. The documentation is here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html